# Python tkinter problems with different classes of windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I've just started to learn tkinter. It's easy when you are trying to use everything in one file, one class. So, i've tryed to make an authorisation system, but met a problem. I can't see the Registration class when I'm trying to call it.I want to see a new window of Registration class, when i can't find user insert. How can it be solved?

My code is:

```
from  tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
# import registration

class Registration(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        # self.loadImage
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()
        

    def initUI(self):

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.label = Label(self, text="Логин")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.login = Entry(self, width=30)
        self.login.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.label2 = Label(self, text="Пароль")
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.passwd = Entry(self, width=30)
        self.passwd.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.ConfirmBtn = tk.Button(self, text="Registrar", padx="5", pady="20",width =40, command = self.registrar)
        self.ConfirmBtn.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan = 3,sticky = W+E)


class Authorisation_De_La_Sistema(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        # self.loadImage
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.label = Label(self, text="Логин")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.login = Entry(self, width=30)
        self.login.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.label2 = Label(self, text="Пароль")
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.passwd = Entry(self, width=30)
        self.passwd.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=20)
        self.ConfirmBtn = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", padx="5", pady="20", command = self.registration)
        self.ConfirmBtn.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan = 3,sticky = W+E)

    def registration(self):
        pass
    #   Registration()
       
            
       
        
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("700x300+300+300")
    app = Authorisation_De_La_Sistema(master=root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: first of remove `*` from your imports and import only the specific things you need (like you do with `from tkinter import Tk`, so do for all the other things and remove the `*`), second, you only need two lines to import stuff like this from tkinter, you can easily remove the `from tkinter import Tk` and `import tkinter as tk` lines and then simply be consistent in using widget class names

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Thank's for advice, I've changed the code. Can you answer now? Without all * it's not working, but I was trying to use them less.

Comment: Now the problem has changed. Window is open but it's empty and not working with mouse events (I can't close or hide it)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see the Registration class when I'm trying to call it.I want
> to see a new window of Registration class, when I can't find user
> insert

Problem can be fixed.

Add `registrar()` function in line 30.

```
 def registrar(self):
        pass
```

You're ready to go.

Screenshot:

[image]